# Problem with start Cisco Packet Tracer 6.3

Tags: cisco

I have problem with Cisco Packet Tracer.I have v. 6.3. I would like to know how fix it. When I use command /usr/local/PacketTracer6/packettracer to run PT I see only Starting Packet Tracer 6.3. Help me. I need this program for study.I install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 but again nothing.

If anyone knows how to fix this problem please guide.
Thank you in advance. :D

Comment: Did you also install Java and perform all the setup instructions [as posted here?](https://www.unixmen.com/installing-cisco-packet-tracer-linux/)  If so, then you should not be using the command you are using, only `sudo packettracer` to start it.

Answer (score 0):

If properly installed, simply start Packet Tracer in terminal with the command

`sudo packettracer`

Ensure you use the `sudo` command.